# Chop video in parts

Tags: ffmpeg

I tried to use this command:

ffmpeg -i "in.mp4" -codec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_list out.txt -segment_times 01:00:00,01:00:00,01:00:00 out%03d.mp4

and expected 1hour long parts. But this is not what I get. What is correct syntax for -segment_times?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I guess all I was needed is -segment_time 01:00:00

Comment: segment_times represents split points, not intervals, so with segment_times it would be `01:00:00,02:00:00,03:00:00`

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks!